# Writing Gentoo ebuilds: how to correctly add libraries using flag-o-matic eclass

Tags: linux, gentoo

I'm trying to write an ebuild (I'm very new to writing ebuilds) and I need to add the library -ltinfo to link against.

My ebuild looks like:

```
EAPI=8
inherit flag-o-matic
...
src_compile() {
    append-libs -ltinfo
    default
}
```

Everything else is pretty much default, but in the emerge log I don't see `-ltinfo` included as a library and it fails to compile.

Comment: I was able to work around this issue by patching the Makefile, but I would still like to be able to do this from within the ebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Makefile used an environment variable LOADLIBS to specify libraries. The following src compile worked without flag-o-matic.

```
src_compile() {
    emake LOADLIBS="..."
}
```